# How to convert Object to new Object with condition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have one object like

```
const data = {
    "title": "new book"
    "IsSale": 1,
    "price" : 100,
}
```

I want to change to

```
const data = {
    "title": "new book"
    "IsSale": true,
    "price" : 100,
}
```

`"IsSale": 1 > "IsSale": true`

If it is array, we can use `reduce` method, to change it. But for Object do we have any method.
Of course, we don't convert to array, deduce, and convert back to Object

Comment: What is your question? How are you determining which poperties to change? But yes, if you need to iterate properties then convert to array first ([`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) . Otherwise provide an array of properties to check separately and iterate that.

Comment: *deduce*? Did you mean [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)?

Answer (score 2):

> If it is array, we can use deduce [sic] method, to change it. But for Object do we have any method.

If it were an array, you'd use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this, not [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (I assume you meant `reduce`). Or an explicit loop.

Just to get it out the way: The simple version is to just write an object literal:

```
const updated = {
    ...data,
    IsSale: !!data.IsSale
};
```

```js
const data = {
    "title": "new book",
    "IsSale": 1,
    "price" : 100,
};

const updated = {
    ...data,
    IsSale: !!data.IsSale
};

console.log(updated);
```

If for some reason you needed to do something other than that, there *is* a way to do something similar with objects, but it involves a lot of intermediary objects. (Often that doesn't matter; sometimes it does.) You **could** use `Object.entries` to get an array of `[key, value]` arrays, then use `map` on that, then use `Object.fromEntries` to convert that back into an object:

```
const updated = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) =>
        [key, key === "IsSale" ? !!value : value]
    )
);
```

```js
const data = {
    "title": "new book",
    "IsSale": 1,
    "price" : 100,
};

const updated = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) =>
        [key, key === "IsSale" ? !!value : value]
    )
);

console.log(updated);
```

Or you might just use a `for-in` loop instead:

```
const updated = {};
for (const key in data) {
    if (Object.hasOwn(data, key)) {
        const value = data[key];
        updated[key] = key === "IsSale" ? !!value : value;
    }
}
```

```js
const data = {
    "title": "new book",
    "IsSale": 1,
    "price" : 100,
};

const updated = {};
for (const key in data) {
    if (Object.hasOwn(data, key)) {
        const value = data[key];
        updated[key] = key === "IsSale" ? !!value : value;
    }
}

console.log(updated);
```

(Note: That uses the newish [`Object.hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn), apply a polyfill if you have to target obsolete environments that don't have it.)

Comment: *(If you don't see the simple version above, hit refresh. Nearly missed the forest for all those trees...)*

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder. I already though about your way.
But still want to find another solution to have the best performance

Comment: @sun1211- Which way are you talking about? The first one (an object literal) will be very, very, very fast. :-) The only thing that *might* be a bit faster would be explicitly listing the properties: `const updated = { title: data.title, IsSale: !!data.IsSale, price: data.price };`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to convert the value of a property within an Object to boolean (`true/false`). Here's a small helper function to do such a conversion. It can be used to add and/or convert the property `IsSale` in an array of objects.

```js
// Note: !!data.IsSale can be used as shorthand
const sale2bool = data => data.IsSale = Boolean(data.IsSale);

const data = [{
    "title": "new book",
    "IsSale": 1,
    "price" : 100,
  }, {
   "title": "another new book",
    "IsSale": 0,
    "price" : 110,
  }, {
    "title": "old book",
    "IsSale": 15,
    "price" : 50,
  }, {
    // Note: no IsSale property
    "title": "old book",
    "price" : 50,
  }];
  
data.forEach(sale2bool);
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```